# How to access event logs in windows.old

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-event-log

I've had a Windows 2008 crash that required reinstall. The old installation is now in windows.old directory.

How can I access those event logs to try figure out what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In event viewer, right click on the Windows Logs node and select "open saved log". You can open event log files directly.

For event sources not (yet) installed on your new install you might not get correct text expansion of course.